# Redirect to a specific path in Angular after login

Tags: angular

When you enter a route on my page, but you must log in first, it must allow you to redirect you to login and after logging in, you must redirect you to the consulted route

For example, if I consult: http://localhost:4200/office/profile I will first have to login and then redirect to that path:

> 

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private _router: Router
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

    if (state.url === '/office_management') {
        if (!this.authService.isAuthenticateManagement()) {
            this._router.navigate(['/auth/mp_access']);
            return false;
        }

    } else {            
        if (!this.authService.isAuthenticate()) {
            this._router.navigate(['/auth/sign_in']);
            return false;
        }
    
    }        
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the redirection with this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

   constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
        const isAuthenticateManagement = this.authService.isAuthenticateManagement();
        const isAuthenticate = this.authService.isAuthenticate();

        if (isAuthenticateManagement || isAuthenticate) return true;

        const root = state.url === '/office_management' ? '/auth/mp_access' : '/auth/sign_in';

        this.router.navigate([root], { queryParams: { redirectURL: state.url }});   

        return false;
  }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you can handle on interseptor that at first you needs to login

And call

```
private _redirectToLoginPage(): void {
    const decodeLocation =        decodeURIComponent(window.location.href);

    Utils.openUrlInThisWindow(`${this.loginUrl}?    ReturnUrl=${decodeLocation}`);
  }
```

openUrlInThisWindow - function window.open